# MICE not imputing all variables with missing values

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice

I'm struggling to get mice to impute all the variables with missing values in my dataset. It's working perfectly for 4 of the variables, but not 3 others (and I'm getting the 3 logged events, which I suspect correspond to the 3 in question: GCSPupils, Hypoxia, Hypotension), but I can't figure out the issue. There seems to be variability in those variables (not constants), so mice should work. I want to do single imputation of 7 variables (the other variables have complete data).

```
# We run the mice code with 0 iterations
imp <- mice(TXAIMPACT_final, maxit = 0)
# Extract predictor Matrix and methods of imputation 
predM <- imp$predictorMatrix
meth <- imp$method
#Setting values of variables I'd like to leave out to 0 in the predictor matrix
predM[,c("subjectId")] <- 0 

# Specify a separate imputation model for variables of interest 

# Dichotomous variable
log <- c("Hypotension", "Hypoxia")

# Unordered categorical variable 
poly2 <- c("GCSPupils", "GCSMotor")

# Turn their methods matrix into the specified imputation models
meth[log] <- "logreg"
meth[poly2] <- "polyreg"
```

Here, I check to make sure "meth" is correct, and it is:

```
meth
subjectId         Age         GCS    GCSMotor   GCSPupils     Glucose  Hemoglobin 
    ""          ""          ""       "polyreg"   "polyreg"       "pmm"       "pmm"    
Hypotension     Hypoxia  MarshallCT     SAH         EDH         GOS        GFAP
"logreg"    "logreg"       "pmm"        ""          ""          ""          ""
```

The methods are all correct as I specified. I do notice something funny about the Predictor Matrix, which is that the 3 variables not imputing only show "0" for their columns:

```
 predM
            subjectId Age GCS GCSMotor GCSPupils Glucose Hemoglobin Hypotension Hypoxia MarshallCT SAH EDH GOS GFAP
subjectId           0   1   1        1         0       1          1           0       0          1   1   1   1    1
Age                 0   0   1        1         0       1          1           0       0          1   1   1   1    1
GCS                 0   1   0        1         0       1          1           0       0          1   1   1   1    1
GCSMotor            0   1   1        0         0       1          1           0       0          1   1   1   1    1
GCSPupils           0   0   0        0         0       0          0           0       0          0   0   0   0    0
Glucose             0   1   1        1         0       0          1           0       0          1   1   1   1    1
Hemoglobin          0   1   1        1         0       1          0           0       0          1   1   1   1    1
Hypotension         0   0   0        0         0       0          0           0       0          0   0   0   0    0
Hypoxia             0   0   0        0         0       0          0           0       0          0   0   0   0    0
MarshallCT          0   1   1        1         0       1          1           0       0          0   1   1   1    1
SAH                 0   1   1        1         0       1          1           0       0          1   0   1   1    1
EDH                 0   1   1        1         0       1          1           0       0          1   1   0   1    1
GOS                 0   1   1        1         0       1          1           0       0          1   1   1   0    1
GFAP                0   1   1        1         0       1          1           0       0          1   1   1   1    0
```

I think this is the problem, but I'm not sure how to solve. Finally, here is my single imputation:

```
imp2 <- complete(mice(TXAIMPACT_final, maxit = 1, 
+              predictorMatrix = predM, 
+              method = meth, print = TRUE))

 iter imp variable
  1   1  GCSMotor  Glucose  Hemoglobin  MarshallCT
  1   2  GCSMotor  Glucose  Hemoglobin  MarshallCT
  1   3  GCSMotor  Glucose  Hemoglobin  MarshallCT
  1   4  GCSMotor  Glucose  Hemoglobin  MarshallCT
  1   5  GCSMotor  Glucose  Hemoglobin  MarshallCT
Warning: Number of logged events: 3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out--posting here in case someone else has this issue. My variables that were not imputing were stored as character classes, which blocked imputation. As soon as I switched them to numeric, my issues disappeared.